# Inserting rows from one table to another where match occurs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

I have two tables `PRODUCTION_HISTORY` and `BULK_INSERT`. I am trying to insert values from `TEST_Custom_DataSets` column from `BULK_INSERT` table to `CUSTOM_DATASETS` in the `PRODUCTION_HISTORY` table where the `WELL_KEY` matches but I am getting the following error:

> The multi-part identifier "dbo.PRODUCTION_HISTORY.WELL_KEY" could not be bound.

Following is my query:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[PRODUCTION_HISTORY] (CUSTOM_DATASETS)
SELECT Test_Custom_DataSets 
FROM [dbo].[BULK_INSERT]
WHERE [dbo].[BULK_INSERT].WELL_KEY = dbo.PRODUCTION_HISTORY.WELL_KEY
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use a join in your select statement.

Comment: I don't see table `dbo.PRODUCTION_HISTORY` in your query.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you just need to join those two tables together in your select statement.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[PRODUCTION_HISTORY] (CUSTOM_DATASETS) 
SELECT Test_Custom_DataSets 
FROM [dbo].[BULK_INSERT] AS bi
JOIN dbo.PRODUCTION_HISTORY AS ph 
    ON bi.WELL_KEY = ph.WELL_KEY
```

Comment: So it executed well but also updated all the nulls all the way up to 76k rows. Is there a way to only update the ones that have well_key data not as null? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want *update*, not *insert*:

```
UPDATE ph
    SET CUSTOM_DATASETS = bi.Test_Custom_DataSets
    FROM [dbo].[PRODUCTION_HISTORY] pn JOIN
         [dbo].[BULK_INSERT] bi
         ON bi.WELL_KEY = pn.WELL_KEY;
```